While debugging, browser closes down while uploading a file using ASPX.Net and C#
I'm using VS2017 and my browser is Microsoft Edge (unfortunately, no other browser, I must use this). Upon selecting the file I want to upload, the debugging immediately stops. Am I missing something?
I have below code for my Upload.aspx:
<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload.aspx">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnupload_Click1" />
        <br />
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="UploadStatus"></asp:Label>  
    </form>

And I have below for my Upload.aspx.cs button:
protected void btnupload_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) && (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + fn;
                try
                {
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    UploadStatus.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    UploadStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UploadStatus.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
            }
        }


The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307947/10024425

ASP.Net Upload Configuration:
ASP.Net has settings for upload size limits. Large files exceeding these limits can cause crashes.
Increase the maxRequestLength in your web.config file under <system.web>. You can also configure maxAllowedContentLength in IIS settings. Search for "[ASP.Net upload large file]" for configuration details.

Does this answer your question? Visual Studio debugging stop immediately on file upload in mvc?

@RahulSharma thanks for that one but unfortunately, I cannot try it using another browser, the requirement was just to use the Microsoft edge. What I did is just close the browser and clean the browsing data. Surprisingly it works. It only works if there's no existing open browser. Can I ask if you have any idea if it will be the same behavior once I deploy the program to IIS?

@itsmePJ I do not believe so. The issue is on local environment only as far as I know.

It seems like your issue might be related to the debugging process rather than the code itself. Visual Studio sometimes stops debugging when certain events occur, such as a file upload.
Check Debugging Settings:  In Visual Studio, go to Debug > Options > Debugging > General. Ensure that "Enable Just My Code" and "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" are checked.
Attach Debugger: Go to Debug > Attach to Process and select your Edge process. This allows you to debug while the file is being uploaded.

Breakpoint: Place a breakpoint in your btnupload_Click1 method and see if it's hit when you click the upload button. This will confirm if the method is being executed or if the debugging is stopping before reaching it.
Check if any exception is being thrown that causes the debugging to stop. Go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and ensure that Common Language Runtime Exceptions are checked.
Check Event Viewer: Check the Windows Event Viewer for any relevant error messages.
